# Using a reversible pool heat pump with independent tank for underfloor cooling and heating

Tags: hvac

If a reversible pool heat pump installed outside, with a solar heater over it for winter,  (the type used for sending hot air into your home) and insulation from the sun in summer, for underfloor heating and cooling.

It will bein a tiny house, about 250²ft, 30²m.

Would I be better with a separate insulated water tank for the circulation?

I am thinking a tank will economise both water or cooling fluid, and energy by recycling hot or cold water.

I have a double coil tank, branched on solar water heaters, and a wood boiler for winter. I intend to use a php only for underfloor heating and cooling, so it will not be in direct contact with the hot water tank. Any additional heat needed will be through a heat exchanger, from hot water tank via a heat exchanger. The same could be used in summer with cold mains water.

For cooling both floor and air in the summer it's the most efficient and inexpensive way I've thought of.

500 watts consumption, giving 2 to 3 kw output from a reversible pool heat pump, for about 500 euros, plus the pipes, underfloor heating boards and hydronic cooler and heater for the air arrival from a ventilator non-centralised.

Has anyone tried this?

To me it seems feasible.